# Running parallel R + Python jobs on AWS?

Tags: python, r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing

I'm used to running parallel `R` and `Python` jobs on my university's cluster using scripts like these. Is there some equivalent in AWS?

At minimum, I want to be able to:

- Launch jobs from Terminal on my Mac
- Run parallelized R/Python functions on 4-8 cores
- Only pay for the time it takes the job to complete

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=8
#SBATCH --output=slurm_%j.out

module load r/3.6.1
Rscript script.R
```

Comment: The first two (launch from terminal, run parallelized r/python on multicore instances) are common AWS use cases.  They do take some setup - either load a pre-made AMI (an "image" loaded with R/Ptython and required libraries), or you can spin up a fresh environment and load everything in yourself.  You pay for instances from spin up to spin down, regardless of whether your job is running.  (You can just include in your AWS setup script a command to shut down after jobs have completed.). But all of this is not really appropriate for an SO question, it's more about devops than coding, per se.

Comment: Do you know of a better forum? I've been searching around for tutorials but haven't found any

Comment: here's a post discussing this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141942/best-stack-exchange-site-for-asking-about-amazon-aws